# Responsive email 3 columns layouts not displayed full width

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I started making a email from a default Mailchimp layout, the "1:3 Column - Full Width" one.

When testing it on diferent devices, I realized that on mobile email client apps (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.), the area marked below is not displayed full width, when should.

[image]

I'm unable to find the mistake, I didn't touch any of the responsive code from the default layout.

-Thanks for your time.

Here is the code:

```css
.templateContainer {
  max-width: 600px !important;
}

.mcnImageCalendar {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .templateContainer {
    width: 600px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .columnWrapper {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" class="templateColumns">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">


                                    <img alt="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="max-width:602px;" class="mcnImage mcnImageCalendar">
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;padding:0 9px 0 9px;text-align: justify;">
                                    <strong>19 July</strong>
                                    <br>Lorem ipsum
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#01a4e2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn_info" style="border-radius:25px; max-width: 175px;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" height="32" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Ubuntu, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:20.4px;">
                                    <div class="editable_text" style="line-height:20.4px; border-radius:25px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:25px; display: block;">
                                        <span class="text_container" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">+ info</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">


                                    <img alt="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="max-width:602px;" class="mcnImage mcnImageCalendar">
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;padding:0 9px 0 9px;text-align: justify;">
                                    <strong>19 July</strong>
                                    <br>Lorem ipsum
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#01a4e2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn_info" style="border-radius:25px; max-width: 175px;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" height="32" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Ubuntu, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:20.4px;">
                                    <div class="editable_text" style="line-height:20.4px; border-radius:25px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:25px; display: block;">
                                        <span class="text_container" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">+ info</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">


                                    <img alt="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="max-width:602px;" class="mcnImage mcnImageCalendar">
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;padding:0 9px 0 9px;text-align: justify;">
                                    <strong>19 July</strong>
                                    <br>Lorem ipsum
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#01a4e2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn_info" style="border-radius:25px; max-width: 175px;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" height="32" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Ubuntu, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:20.4px;">
                                    <div class="editable_text" style="line-height:20.4px; border-radius:25px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:25px; display: block;">
                                        <span class="text_container" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">+ info</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pls let me know at which device resolution  your facing this issue...

Comment: @Santhoshkumar devices with display's resolution of 720x1280 pixels, size 4.8 and 5.0 inches

Comment: pls check the answer @Qu4k3

Comment: @Santhoshkumar Sorry for the delay, still testing it.

Comment: No problem @Qu4k3, take your time, Thanks :)....

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do (if applicable) is to move ALL inline code to a proper CSS style block. Currently, you keep repeating styles with each `<table>`. What if you need to modify a few layout issues, say, like now? Modify all relevant inline code? Help yourself and modify like I suggested, saves the mood and keeps your hair where it belongs, on top (provided you're not bald).

Comment: @RenevanderLende not all email clients support style tags - they strip them out

Comment: @Laim One has to love to hate email clients. Neverthless, the structure of the template seems to leave a lot to be desired (which is not the OP's fault, btw, but Mailchimp's).

Comment: try `align="center"` for the td that contains all the tables. I am not sure if it will work but give it a try. I am more used to building emails using the hybrid method.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, u need to mention min-width and max-width

```css
.templateContainer {
  max-width: 600px !important;
}

.mcnImageCalendar {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
  .templateContainer {
    width: 600px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .columnWrapper {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" class="templateColumns">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">


                                    <img alt="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="max-width:602px;" class="mcnImage mcnImageCalendar">
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;padding:0 9px 0 9px;text-align: justify;">
                                    <strong>19 July</strong>
                                    <br>Lorem ipsum
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#01a4e2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn_info" style="border-radius:25px; max-width: 175px;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" height="32" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Ubuntu, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:20.4px;">
                                    <div class="editable_text" style="line-height:20.4px; border-radius:25px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:25px; display: block;">
                                        <span class="text_container" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">+ info</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">


                                    <img alt="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="max-width:602px;" class="mcnImage mcnImageCalendar">
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;padding:0 9px 0 9px;text-align: justify;">
                                    <strong>19 July</strong>
                                    <br>Lorem ipsum
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#01a4e2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn_info" style="border-radius:25px; max-width: 175px;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" height="32" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Ubuntu, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:20.4px;">
                                    <div class="editable_text" style="line-height:20.4px; border-radius:25px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:25px; display: block;">
                                        <span class="text_container" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">+ info</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding:9px;">

                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">


                                    <img alt="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="max-width:602px;" class="mcnImage mcnImageCalendar">
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;padding:0 9px 0 9px;text-align: justify;">
                                    <strong>19 July</strong>
                                    <br>Lorem ipsum
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#01a4e2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn_info" style="border-radius:25px; max-width: 175px;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" height="32" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Ubuntu, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:20.4px;">
                                    <div class="editable_text" style="line-height:20.4px; border-radius:25px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 16px;border-radius:25px; display: block;">
                                        <span class="text_container" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">+ info</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The result still the same... maybe Michael is right, and there is no way to achieve this on **email client apps**, at least right now.

Answer (score 0):

First - not every email clients use media queries. For example gmail don't. So Your email won't be responsive on gmail and many email clients like Outlook etc. I create my last email template for shop about year ago so do not remember every behavior but this is great tool https://litmus.com .

And what I remember - use only inline styles and tables in template. Good luck because creating email template is a terrible work :)

Comment: In September/October 2016 Gmail started supporting media queries https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design. I think it's more about priority in the client's css reading. Yeah... it's terrible to make an email looks correct in every device.

Comment: Nice info but: Gmail Android app (POP/IMAP account) - NO, Mobile webmail - NO ... So if I understand, mobiles apps do not use media queries but only desktop ... so who needs this ? :)

Comment: People who don't feel like designing emails for each and every device type?